# SQlite PHP injection

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

Olá, pessoal!
Atualmente estou utilizando sqlite em um projeto pessoal e estou utilizando esta classe: https://github.com/TimOliver/PHP-Framework-Classes/blob/master/db.sqlite.class.php

Quando eu uso a função query dela, eu estou sucetível à SQLinjection, por exemplo neste exemplo:

```
$login=$database ->get_row('SELECT * from usuarios where login="'.$login.'" and senha="'.$senha.'"',$resultado);
```

Ao usar as aspas, ele quebra minha query e acaba ficando exposto à sql injection. Eu tentei fazer algumas coisas mas não tive sucesso ao prevenir isso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no método `prepare` dessa classe?

Comment: Já, algumas funções utilizam ela. Quando eu uso a get_row ela não passa a query por isso. Tentei fazer ele levar pra lá mas não tive muito resultado possitivo :/